# How to add a string as data to a dataset?

Tags: matlab

I use the following code to create a simple dataset and add the first two rows:

```
data = dataset([1; 2],[3; 4],'VarNames', {'A', 'B'})
```

After that, I would like to set the value 4 to 'test':

```
 data(1,2) = 'test'
```

Since this throws the following exception:

```
Error using dataset/subsasgnParens (line 198)
Right hand side must be a dataset array.
Error in dataset/subsasgn (line 79)
    a = subsasgnParens(a,s,b,creating);
```

I also tried:

```
data(1,2) = dataset('test');
```

But this is also not working. Therefore my question: How can I add a String to a dataset such as I have created, using the method I'm using (I have to specify the row and column)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do

```
data(1,2) = dataset('test');
```

because `'test'` is char type and the rest of your data are doubles and because the string `'test'` is four elements which you're trying to put into one element of an array.

You need to use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). If you want to use the `dataset` function capabilities, see the [`cell2dataset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cell2dataset.html) and [`dataset2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.dataset2cell.html) functions. For example:

```
data = dataset([1; 2],[3; 4],'VarNames',{'A', 'B'})
data2 = dataset2cell(data);
data2{3,1} = 'test';
data3 = cell2dataset(data2,'ReadVarNames',true');
```